# iOS 8 UITableViewCell extra broken separators

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout, ios8

OK, I don't know what's up with iOS 8 but when I run my app on it, I see these extra UITableViewSeparatorViews:

[image]

### Update

I used the Xcode 6 View Debugger and I see that in this problematic UITableView, I see these extra views being added as a subview of my UITableViewCellContentView

**_UITableViewCellSeparatorView**

Why does iOS 8 add these random subviews to my cell's contentView ?

As you can see from the screenshot, those extra lines are the ones that doesn't reach the edge of the screen.

In my view controller, I am using the following code to make the lines go all the way to the edge of the screen:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    cell.contentView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

    if ([tableView respondsToSelector:@selector(setSeparatorInset:)]) {
        [tableView setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }

    if ([tableView respondsToSelector:@selector(setLayoutMargins:)]) {
        [tableView setLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }

    if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setLayoutMargins:)]) {
        [cell setLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }
}
```

In my custom cell class, I am setting:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code

        _reuseID = reuseIdentifier;
        self.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        self.contentView.backgroundColor = [[BSGThemeManager sharedTheme] clearColor];

        self.contentView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

        self.containerView = [[UIView alloc] init];

        _photo = [[BSGUserPhotoView alloc] init];
        [_photo clipPhotoToRadius:37.5];
        //_photo.layer.cornerRadius = 37.5 / 2.0;
        //_photo.layer.borderColor = [[BSGThemeManager sharedTheme] photoBorderColor];
        //_photo.layer.borderWidth = [[BSGThemeManager sharedTheme] photoBorderWidth];
        //_photo.clipsToBounds = YES;

        self.photo.alpha = 0;

        _message = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        _message.backgroundColor = [[BSGThemeManager sharedTheme] clearColor];
        _message.numberOfLines = 0;
        _message.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
        _message.font = [[BSGThemeManager sharedTheme] varelaRoundFontWithSize:15];

        self.message.alpha = 0;

        _time = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        _time.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
        _time.font = [[BSGThemeManager sharedTheme] helveticaNeueFontWithSize:16];
        _time.textColor = [[BSGThemeManager sharedTheme] postTimeColor];
        [_time setContentCompressionResistancePriority:UILayoutPriorityRequired forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisHorizontal];
        [_time setContentHuggingPriority:UILayoutPriorityRequired forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisHorizontal];

        self.time.alpha = 0;

        [self.containerView addSubview:_photo];
        [self.containerView addSubview:_message];
        [self.containerView addSubview:_time];

        [self.contentView addSubview:self.containerView];

        [self addAllConstraints];
    }
    return self;
}
```

I'm not sure if this line was the cause of it:

```
self.contentView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

My Autolayout code for my cell is:

```
-(void)addAllConstraints
{
    self.containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    self.photo.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    self.message.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    self.time.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    id views = @{
                 @"containerView": self.containerView,
                 @"photo": self.photo,
                 @"message": self.message,
                 @"time": self.time
                 };

    [self.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[containerView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
    [self.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[containerView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];


    // --------------------------------------------------
    // Horizontal Constraints
    // --------------------------------------------------

    [self.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-10-[photo(37.5)]-15-[message(195)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];

    [self.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[time]-10-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];

    // --------------------------------------------------
    // Vertical Constraints
    // --------------------------------------------------

    [self.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[photo(37.5)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];

    [self.contentView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.photo attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.contentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];

    [self.contentView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.message attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.photo attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];

    [self.contentView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.time attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.photo attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];
}
```

Anyone else came across this weird iOS 8 bug?

It doesn't show up on iOS 7.

Comment: Your answer didnt work for me. Any other solution?

Comment: Don't know, do you have any conflicting constraints in the console output ? In my case, I made sure I don't have any conflicting constraints first. Maybe post another Stackoverflow question with your source code so others can see and hopefully offer a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lol....OK...I think I fixed this problem.

One of my subview is called "message" which is just a UILabel.

On my custom tableview cell's class, this code was causing the extra line to appear:

```
-(void)layoutSubviews
{
    self.message.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = self.bounds.size.width * 0.75;
}
```

After getting rid of it, the cells behaved how I liked it to like in iOS 7.

Comment: try keeping it and also calling the super, like in the init

Answer (score 2):

I found an easy solution, when i overwrote the `layoutSubviews` method, i also called the super method as well, like so:

```
-(void)layoutSubviews {
[super layoutSubviews];
// rest of custom implementation code here
. . . 
}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

[image]
Change the highlighted to '0' then the it resolves. It was through XIB.

Comment: The problem is not the left edge spacing, the problem is I'm getting these extra lines out of the blue in iOS 8. I've already set the tableView's separator insets to UIEdgeInsetsZero in the above code. It's working fine in iOS 7, but not in iOS 8.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the dynamic height of the custom tableViewCells was causing an issue, to be specific, the `heightForRowAtIndexPath` and `estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath` delegate methods. One worked perfect for iOS 7 and the other for iOS 8. Solved it by conditionally checking for the iOS version.